# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in node_modules -> elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, elasticsearch

While trying to write a function to deploy on Firebase Function, I wrote this code:

```
'use strict';
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const Promise  = require('promise');

const config = {
    firebaseUrl: FIREBASE_URL,
    elasticSearchUrl: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
};
// configure firebase
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: config.firebaseUrl
});
const database = firebaseAdmin.database();
const client =  new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: config.elasticSearchUrl
});
exports.indexentry = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postid}/text').onWrite(event => {
  let data = event.data.val();
  let post_id = event.params.postid;

  let indexData = {
        index: "firebase",
        type: "posts",
        id: post_id,
        body: data
    }

  return client.index(indexData).then(response => {
    console.log('Response: ');
  });
});
```

I get an error:

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:440:38)
    at Log.listenerCount (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\fbfn_10872H41uMk66c53o\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:442:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\fbfn_10872H41uMk66c53o\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:442:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\fbfn_10872H41uMk66c53o\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:442:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\fbfn_10872H41uMk66c53o\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:442:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\fbfn_10872H41uMk66c53o\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:442:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\fbfn_10872H41uMk66c53o\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:442:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\fbfn_10872H41uMk66c53o\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\log.js:68:25)
    at Function.EventEmitter.listenerCount (events.js:442:20)
    at Log.listenerCount (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\fbfn_10872H41uMk66c53o\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\log.js:68:25)
```

In one of the comments on Github I found a fix:
It asked me to add this anywhere in my code:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var Log = require('./node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log');
Log.prototype.listenerCount = EventEmitter.prototype.listenerCount;
```

Now I get an error:

```
Error: unknown error at respond (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:234:15) at checkRespForFailure (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:200:7) at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:155:7) at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19) at emitNone (events.js:91:20) at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12) at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
 Error: unknown error
    at respond (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:234:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:200:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:155:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

How to fix this?

**EDIT**

I updated elasticsearch as suggested in the first answer. Now I get the error:

```
 Error: [mapper_parsing_exception] failed to parse
        at respond (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:307:15)
        at checkRespForFailure (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:266:7)
        at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:159:7)
        at IncomingMessage.bound (/user_code/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
        at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
        at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
        at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you're using a recent version of elastic search: `npm install elasticsearch`. Add the right dependency in your `package.json` file, it should be a recent version of elastic search, or, use the commad, `npm install elasticsearch@13.2.0` or any other version.
2. You do not need to actually override `Log.prototype.listenerCount`, elasticsearch is already doing that for you internally (hence, the call stack recursion). So, remove this line:

`Log.prototype.listenerCount = EventEmitter.prototype`

Also, while this is unrelated to your issue... it is redundant to include `./node_modules` in your require paths. Node has a module-searching mechanism built-in already and does this for u.

Comment: Please see the edit part. New error and I am as clueless.

Comment: What version of node are u using?

Comment: It looks like its having trouble connecting to your kibana database... make sure the database is live and your credentials are correct.

Comment: no I just checked, a locally running node script is working for a dummy firebase project. The database is getting indexed.